# How to get access to TemplateRef from Outside a Component

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

[From the doc,](https://webdev.dartlang.org/api/angular/angular/TemplateRef-class) I can read:

> Alternatively you can query for the TemplateRef from a Component or a Directive via Query.

Question:

How to `Query` a `TemplateRef` from an external `Component`?

Here some code from the doc:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'child-cmp',
  template: '<p>child</p>',
)
class ChildCmp {
  void doSomething() {}
}

@Component(
  selector: 'some-cmp',
  template: '''
    <child-cmp #child1></child-cmp>
    <child-cmp #child2></child-cmp>
    <child-cmp #child3></child-cmp>
  ''',
  directives: [ChildCmp],
)
class SomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren('child1, child2, child3')
  List<ChildCmp> children;

  @override
  void ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Initial children are set
    for (var child in children) {
      child.doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

How from `SomeCmp` can I get `ChildCmp`'s TemplateRef. What should I do?

Comment: What is an "external Component"? Can you please add some code that provides more detail about your use case. Where exactly is the `TemplateRef` in Component B that you want to get access to?

Comment: I hope it will be more clear now.

Comment: `TemplateRef` is not related to `template: '...',`. `TemplateRef` is a reference to `<template>some content</template>` that you can pass around to be "stamped" somewhere in an Angular component. It would be helpful if you could elaborate what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, it was not clear for me. Seems I have a lot of trouble with the documentation, that **I** really find inaccurate. Anyway, what I want is simple: load arbitrarily `ChildCmp` template's in ` SomeCmp` template's, with  `_loader.loadXXX()`. For this I need to get the `TemplateRef` of `ChildCmp`.

Comment: You need to add the functionality to `ChildCmp` and then you can make it accept a component factory (as an `@Input()`) to `ChildCmp` to render it for the parent. Alternatively you can use `<ng-content>` to add it in the parent but show it inside the child (actually not sure this works for dynamically added components, but there might be ways to make it work anyway)

Comment: Well, much more complex that I would thought at first glance… I will leave this for now, I maybe return to it later…

Comment: Angular takes away some freedom but it gives you more efficiency in return.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to access a component's template ref but if you figure that out then you can simply make that a public property in the child component and access it from the parent.

A workaround that I did is simply use an `<ng-template>` to store the child's template and render it in an `<ng-container>`. I them store the reference to that ng-template in the child component as a public property and it is easily accessible from the parent. I don't believe this is the cleanest solution but it satisfies your question.

You can check out my solution at this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kahwbz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please add relevant part of 'your solution' int this answer